# from Grub to initramfs to end kernel panic - surface 3

Tags: grub, initramfs, kernel-panic

I installed lubuntu on my surface 3 and after updating it and restarting, it took me to grub so I did the following commands:

```
grub> set root=(hd1,msdos1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz(version no.)
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img (version no.)
grub> boot
```

which I saw on a linux.com website for how to rescue a non-booting grub2 on Linux.
Then it took me to initramfs.
It seems though that anything I do on initramfs and in the end I type "exit" it says `end kernel panic - not syncing: attempt to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100`

Comment: sorry the grub goes as follows grub>set root=(hd1,msdos1)grub>linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-10-generic grub>initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-10-generic grub>boot

Comment: and on the initramfs shows mount: cant find /root in etc/fstab , and mounting /dev on /root/dev failed not such file or directory, also target filesystem does not have /sbin/init

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Please, add the relevant information to your question (instead of commenting on it), you can [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/513204/edit) it as much as you need.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer sorry
here it is
in grub 
grub> set root=(hd0,1) selinux=0 enforcing=0
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub> boot